# How to update a record in a mongodb using CrudRepository Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

So I have managed to save a ver simple document into my `User` collection. I want to update a certain field in it but not sure how. My repository is extending from CrudRepo like this:

```
public interface UserMongoRepository extends CrudRepository<User,String> {}
```

And I use the `@Autowire UserMongoRespository userRepo` annotation in whichever class I want to access the database in.

I have the id of the user I would like to update but I don't know how to do that using my repo as it doesn't contain a method to update the record.

UPDATE = When I use the save method, it get the following error:

```
{  
   "serverUsed":"localhost:27017",
   "ok":1,
   "n":0,
   "err":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: car_dealer.user index: _id_ dup key: { : 0 }",
   "code":11000
}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey:{  
   "serverUsed":"localhost:27017",
   "ok":1,
   "n":0,
   "err":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: car_dealer.user index: _id_ dup key: { : 0 }",
   "code":11000
}
```

And also when I debug and view the ID of the user, mongo does not seem to be generating a randomized ID even though I'd annotated the `id` field as `@Id`. Instead it just gives it an ID of zero (I've only got one record in my datbase at the moment).

This is my user class:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String secret;

    public int getNumberOfAttempts() {
        return numberOfAttempts;
    }

    public void setNumberOfAttempts(int numberOfAttempts) {
        this.numberOfAttempts = numberOfAttempts;
    }

    private int numberOfAttempts;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: car_dealer.user index: _id_ dup key: { : 0 }" , "code" : 11000}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getWriteException(CommandResult.java:88) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.translateBulkWriteException(DBCollectionImpl.java:316) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:191) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$9.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1002) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:997) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:810) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:749) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:76) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tests4geeks.tutorials.controllers.VerificationController.verifyingWord(VerificationController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: could you share the class User?

Comment: @cralfaro I have shared the user class

Comment: @lualover2017 delete all documents in the user collection and try to save/update again

Comment: @cralfaro I have and still same error

Comment: did you change also from int to BigInteger? could you paste the java stacktrace?

Comment: @cralfaro No I haven't converted it from BigInteger. I'll post the stacktrace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142921/discussion-between-lualover2017-and-cralfaro).

Answer (score 2):

```
try,
first get the record from the database,
userRepo.findOne(id).
then use saveandflush for update,
userRepo.saveAndFlush(entity).
```

Comment: In UserMongoRepository change Id as Wrapper class Integer because as you declare int is Id in User Class.
Or change Strring as Id in User class.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, in your repository class, you define the PK as String, so you have to create the id as String. Modify your code to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
```

Comment: @lualover2017 can you check my response again? I saw in your repository you define the PK as String, and we used BigInteger before